# What does 下头 mean?

Tags: word

I know the word 上头 means "go to head" as in 这酒很上头(the alcohol is too strong and people may easily get drunk), but what about 下头 as in the sentence这个渣男真是让人下头？

Answer (score 4):

Good question!

下头：maybe: be a  wet blanket?

The Great God Baidu has this for 下头：

网络流行语，
(a) fashionable internet phrase,
有‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌扫兴，
has the meanings: dampen one’s spirits
破坏已有气氛，
spoil the atmosphere,
泼冷水的意思。
be a wet blanket.

和上头相反，
The opposite of 上头，
上头是令人沉迷其中，
上头 means be absorbed, engrossed in something,
下头就是因为某种原因令人被浇灭热情，
下头 has the meaning: for some reason something or someone makes you lose your enthusiasm or passion,
从沉迷、享受的状态迅速走出。
(something) makes you rapidly lose your feeling of being engrossed or absorbed in something, takes away your enjoyment.

Comment: Man what a party pooper. You didn't have to be such a killjoy.

Answer (score 1):

"下头" is an adjective which means "disgusting". It is not a formal expression, can only be seen on Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we will use 下头 with these emojis  ，which means the behaviors we encounter make us feel disgust or uncomfortable.

下头 is a very latest network phrase, and it often appears in the issues of gender opposition.

For example :

臭郭楠，真下头

In this sentence, 郭楠 has the similar pronounce with 国男， refering to normal Chinese males who probably do something to annoy girls (However, in some occasions, the boys do nothing wrong, but the girls still think them disgusting...)

Here are some occasions we may think a person is 下头

> 我和其他模特出去喝酒，有一个哥们不停的在吹嘘多少女人追她，为他是从，我听上去很不是滋味，我们都是190 长相都是属于帅的，谁身边也不缺女孩，而且 女孩喜欢你是认可你，这不代表你可以随便把人家踩在脚下，我们6个人 5个人满脸尴尬 就他越讲越起劲，给我恶心坏了
> ---https://www.zhihu.com/question/492860479/answer/2537019213

This above is quted from Zhihu, a Chinese website like Quora.

Even in Zhihu, there is a question talking about : when do you feel 下头 about a person, here is the link https://www.zhihu.com/question/492860479

Answer (score 0):

From where did you get all those meanings? In the translators i tried, put: 下头 == "down" / "lower head".
(google translator and deepl translator).

Would it be like "thumb down from Caesar"? Disapproval?